# Linking library using Eclipse Kepler under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu-12.04, linker-errors

I have developed a project under Mac OS X 10.8.3, now I need the same project to work under Ubuntu 12.04 LTS.

Inside my project I need to use a library, let's call it libXXX. I have the libXXX.a file and the XXX.h header file. What I did under Mac OS X is change the setting for the project to include the xxx library and of course set the library path to locate it.

I did the exact same thing under Ubuntu but I got a linking error, saying ld cannot find the xxx library.

If anyone has any idea how to solve the issue, that would be great.

Thank you everyone

Comment: Could you actually tell us what that "same thing" was, just so it can be double checked?

Comment: By the "same thing" I mean that I went under the Settings options in the C/C++ Build menu in project properties, selected Libraries under Cross G++ Linker and put the project path in the Library search path (-L) field and xxx in the Libraries (-l) field